# cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression

Tags: c#, indexing, expression

```
 var dbPerson = from p in db.People 
                where p.Id == PersonId select p;
 dbPerson[0].HolidaysRemaining--;
```

is throwing me an error with dbPerson[0] saying cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'system.linq.lqueryable,holidayBookingApp.model.person>

can someone please advise how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `.First()` or `.ElementAt(index)` Or in this case since it appears to be a single row, `.Single()` ie `dbPerson.Single().HolidaysRemaining--;`

Comment: convert your Linq with ToList() in the end

Comment: @asawyer thank you I used  dbPerson.Single().HolidaysRemaining--;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first item that your query `dbPerson` returns, use

```
var firstPerson = dbPerson.First();
```

or `Single` if you only expect one match and want an exception to be thrown if this expectation is broken.

However, I'm not convinced `firstPerson.HolidaysRemaining--;` will change anything in your database without further code:

```
var dbPeopleWithThisId = from p in db.People 
                         where p.Id == PersonId
                         select p;
var specificPerson = dbPeopleWithThisId.Single();
specificPerson.HolidaysRemaining--;
db.SaveChanges(); // Thanks to J. Steen
```

Comment: `db.SaveChanges();` should suffice. Hopefully.

Comment: @J.Steen Thanks for that; I don't use LINQ-to-whatever myself.

Comment: I'm merely assuming this is Linq-To-Entities, but this is a separate question from OP's issue, so I just made it a comment. =)

Comment: @Rawling I used dbPerson.Single().HolidaysRemaining--; Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

The result of your LINQ query is not a `List`, it's a custom type of `IQueryable` that does not have an indexer. You cannot get random access to the results of a LINQ query in that form.

You have multiple options if you really need that:

- Convert it to something that implements `IList`, e.g. call `dbPerson.ToList()`.
- If you really need just the first element, use the `IQueryable` extension method for that purpose: `dbPerson.First()`
- If you want an arbitrary element as `[x]`, use the `IQueryable` extension method for that purpose: `dbPerson.Skip(x).First()`

Comment: `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`. `ElementAt` won't translate.

Comment: Rawling is correct here, it's right in the question: `System.Linq.IQueryable<HolidayBookingApp.Model.Person>`

Comment: bah, you're right; i even had skip/take instead at first and "fixed" it :\

Answer (score 2):

It's because `dbPerson` is IEnumerable, what doesn't support indexing concept. You can use some Linq methods, like `dbPerson.First()`, or simply convert it to List:

```
var list = dbPerson.ToList();
list[0].HolidaysRemaining--;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand the idea behind the Linq & IEnumerable (& IQueryable) interface. IEnumerable used for lazy loading of sequences, so if you create an extension method for loop like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> LazyForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) //action to perform                
        {
            if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
            foreach (T element in source)
            {
                action(element);
                yield return element;
            }
        }
```

and try to use LazyForEach in IEnumerable-returning method (Linq) chain:

```
db.People.Where(p=>p...).LazyForEach(p=>
{
   MessageBox.Show(p.ToString());
});
```

your code in provided action will not execute until you force enumeration (maybe partial) with ToList/ToArray/ElementAt/First/Last/Any/Take/Skip ... or you can create alt. extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
        {
            if (source == null)
                return null;
            if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
            //var sourceList = source.ToList(); //forcing enumeration
            var sourceList = new List<T>();
            foreach (var element in source)
            {
                action(element);
                sourceList.Add(element);
            }
            return sourceList;
        }
```