# CSV file read, then sort, then use array again

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

any help on this scenario please.. new to c#.

Summary:

1. Need to read the contents of csv into array.
2. Skip first line of array, then sort on column 1 (company)
3. Then use sorted array (without header if easier) further along in code.

Example csv:

```
 Company,Item,Vendor
 Comp1,Bulb,BnQ
 Comp2,Plug,Tesco
 Comp1,Kettle,Wickes
```

This is my attempt but I get the following error when attempting to access sorted[j] and I cant work out a way around this.

Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Code:

```
var csvRows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(1);
var sorted = csvRows.Select(line => new
                {
                    SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[0]),
                    Line = line
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
                .Select(x => x.Line);

int maxCount = sorted.Count();

for (int j = 0; j < maxCount; j++)
{
 string line1 = sorted[j].ToString();
 var values = line1.Split(',');
...
```

Comment: Pretty sure adding `.ToList()` will work: `.Select(x => x.Line).ToList();`, otherwise you can `foreach` instead of `for`: `foreach (var line in sorted) { var line1 = line.ToString(); ...`

Comment: @Quantic thanks, I will give this a go and see if it works for me

Comment: You should really learn to Google these exception messages.  Typing `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` directly into Google tells you how to fix it.

Comment: @DarrenYoung appreciate the advice, albeit condescending. It was the first thing I did, but still failed to find a solution - hence the post.

Comment: When I do as @DarrenYoung says I get [Cannot apply indexing with __ to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<int> in mvc controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020001/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-system-collections-gener) and [cannot apply indexing with __ to an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879416/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression).

Comment: Please be aware that `Split(',')` only parses a [tiny subset of valid CSV files](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble). If you ever need to parse a more typical file you need to use a CSV parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`to the end of the LINQ query, otherwise your sorted variable is IEnumerable and not list or array, so you cant access it with an index.